# Deploy Jersey Application to Tomcat - Resources 404

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have a tree that looks like this:

[image]

In the java folder, I have a package, `com.example.project` which has a `Main` class and an `Application` class that subclasses `ResourceConfig`

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application() {
        packages("com.example.project");
        property(MustacheMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "templates");
        register(MustacheMvcFeature.class);
        register(MyRequestFilter.class);
    }
}
```

In development, I run the `Main` class and start a Grizzly server:

```
public class Main {

    public static HttpServer startServer(String BASE_URI) {
        final Application app = new Application();
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), app);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/api";
        final HttpServer server = startServer(BASE_URI);

        server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
                new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/webapp"), "/");

        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%s/application.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI)
        );

        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with the Grizzly server. I'm now trying to deploy to tomcat.

I use `mvn package` to create a war file. In my pom file, I have:

```xml
<build>
    ...
        <plugins>
        ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I put the war file in the webapps directory under a tomcat instance and it gets exploded there. My static content is served.

The layout of the directory that comes from the WAR file looks like this:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos6 project]$ tree .
.
├── index.html
| ... <webapp content>
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── com.example.project
│           └── project
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── example
    │   │       └── project
    │   │           ├── Application.class
    │   │           ├── Main.class
    |   |           ...
    │   ├── filter-dev.properties
    │   ├── filter-test.properties
    │   ├── hibernate.cfg.xml
    │   └── templates
    │       └── foo.mustache
    └── lib
       ...
```

I can not locate any of my REST services. Everything I try is 404.

Directory in tomcat webapps is `project`, `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath` is `api`, `@Path` is `service`. So, I would hope to get a response from `/project/api/service`, for instance. But, after trying many combinations, everything is 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jersey-servlet.jar` to your war file.

In `pom.xml`, that might look like this:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```